# Installing WebDriverIO with Typescrit and Cucumber gives me an error

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io

When I finish configuring the project, the `wdio.conf.ts` and `tsconfig.json` files are saved in a folder called tests and the `wdio.conf.ts` file gives me the following error in this line:

```js
    import type { Options } from "@wdio/types";  //which is located in the wdio.conf.ts file
```

And the error says:

```
    > Cannot find module '@wdio/types'. Did you mean to set the
    > 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths'
    > option
```

This is my `wdio.conf.ts` file, which is the default that comes with the project.

```js
    import type { Options } from "@wdio/types";
    
    export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
      //
      // ====================
      // Runner Configuration
      // ====================
      //
      //
      // =====================
      // ts-node Configurations
      // =====================
      //
      // You can write tests using TypeScript to get autocompletion and type safety.
      // You will need typescript and ts-node installed as devDependencies.
      // WebdriverIO will automatically detect if these dependencies are installed
      // and will compile your config and tests for you.
      // If you need to configure how ts-node runs please use the
      // environment variables for ts-node or use wdio config's autoCompileOpts section.
      //
    
      autoCompileOpts: {
        autoCompile: true,
        // see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options
        // for all available options
        tsNodeOpts: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          project: "test/tsconfig.json",
        },
        // tsconfig-paths is only used if "tsConfigPathsOpts" are provided, if you
        // do please make sure "tsconfig-paths" is installed as dependency
        tsConfigPathsOpts: {
          baseUrl: "./",
        },
      },
      //
      // ==================
      // Specify Test Files
      // ==================
      // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
      // from which `wdio` was called.
      //
      // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
      // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
      // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
      // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
      //
      // If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
      // then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
      // will be called from there.
      //
      specs: ["./features/**/*.feature"],
      // Patterns to exclude.
      exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
      ],
      //
      // ============
      // Capabilities
      // ============
      // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
      // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
      // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
      // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
      //
      // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
      // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
      // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
      // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
      // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
      // from the same test should run tests.
      //
      maxInstances: 10,
      //
      // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
      // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
      // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
      //
      capabilities: [
        {
          // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
          // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
          // 5 instances get started at a time.
          maxInstances: 5,
          //
          browserName: "chrome",
          acceptInsecureCerts: true,
          // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
          // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
          // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
          // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
        },
      ],
      //
      // ===================
      // Test Configurations
      // ===================
      // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
      //
      // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
      logLevel: "info",
      //
      // Set specific log levels per logger
      // loggers:
      // - webdriver, webdriverio
      // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
      // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
      // - @wdio/local-runner
      // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
      // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
      // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
      // logLevels: {
      //     webdriver: 'info',
      //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
      // },
      //
      // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
      // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
      bail: 0,
      //
      // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
      // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
      // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
      // gets prepended directly.
      baseUrl: "http://localhost",
      //
      // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
      waitforTimeout: 10000,
      //
      // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
      // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
      connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
      //
      // Default request retries count
      connectionRetryCount: 3,
      //
      // Test runner services
      // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
      // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
      // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
      services: ["chromedriver"],
    
      // Framework you want to run your specs with.
      // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
      // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
      //
      // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
      // before running any tests.
      framework: "cucumber",
      //
      // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
      // specFileRetries: 1,
      //
      // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
      // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
      //
      // Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
      // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
      //
      // Test reporter for stdout.
      // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
      // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
      reporters: ["spec"],
    
      //
      // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
      cucumberOpts: {
        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        require: ["./features/step-definitions/steps.ts"],
        // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        backtrace: false,
        // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        requireModule: [],
        // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        dryRun: false,
        // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        failFast: false,
        // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        snippets: true,
        // <boolean> hide source uris
        source: true,
        // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        strict: false,
        // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        tagExpression: "",
        // <number> timeout for step definitions
        timeout: 60000,
        // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
      },
    
      //
      // =====
      // Hooks
      // =====
      // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
      // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
      // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
      // resolved to continue.
      /**
       * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
       * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       */
      // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
       * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
       * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
       * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
       * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
       * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized
       * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
       */
      // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.
       * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
       * @param  {Number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
       * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
       * @param  {Number} retries  number of retries used
       */
      // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
       * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
       * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
       * @param {String} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
       */
      // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
       * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
       * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
       */
      // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
      // },
      /**
       * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
       * @param {String} commandName hook command name
       * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
       */
      // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
      // },
      /**
       * Cucumber Hooks
       *
       * Runs before a Cucumber Feature.
       * @param {String}                   uri      path to feature file
       * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object
       */
      // beforeFeature: function (uri, feature) {
      // },
      /**
       *
       * Runs before a Cucumber Scenario.
       * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world    world object containing information on pickle and test step
       * @param {Object}                 context  Cucumber World object
       */
      // beforeScenario: function (world, context) {
      // },
      /**
       *
       * Runs before a Cucumber Step.
       * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step     step data
       * @param {IPickle}            scenario scenario pickle
       * @param {Object}             context  Cucumber World object
       */
      // beforeStep: function (step, scenario, context) {
      // },
      /**
       *
       * Runs after a Cucumber Step.
       * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step             step data
       * @param {IPickle}            scenario         scenario pickle
       * @param {Object}             result           results object containing scenario results
       * @param {boolean}            result.passed    true if scenario has passed
       * @param {string}             result.error     error stack if scenario failed
       * @param {number}             result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds
       * @param {Object}             context          Cucumber World object
       */
      // afterStep: function (step, scenario, result, context) {
      // },
      /**
       *
       * Runs after a Cucumber Scenario.
       * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world            world object containing information on pickle and test step
       * @param {Object}                 result           results object containing scenario results
       * @param {boolean}                result.passed    true if scenario has passed
       * @param {string}                 result.error     error stack if scenario failed
       * @param {number}                 result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds
       * @param {Object}                 context          Cucumber World object
       */
      // afterScenario: function (world, result, context) {
      // },
      /**
       *
       * Runs after a Cucumber Feature.
       * @param {String}                   uri      path to feature file
       * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object
       */
      // afterFeature: function (uri, feature) {
      // },
    
      /**
       * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
       * @param {String} commandName hook command name
       * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
       * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
       * @param {Object} error error object if any
       */
      // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
       * the test.
       * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
       */
      // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
       * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
       */
      // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
       * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
       * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
       * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
       * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
       * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
       */
      // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
      // },
      /**
       * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
       * @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
       * @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
       */
      // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
      // }
    };
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file

```json
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "types": [
                "node",
                "webdriverio/async",
                "@wdio/cucumber-framework",
                "expect-webdriverio"
            ],
            "target": "es2019"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try to remove line 1 completely

```
import type { Options } from "@wdio/types";
```

and make line 3 say:

```
export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
```

instead of

```
export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
```

I would then try `npm install` just to be sure

and btw my tsconfig.json has `"target": "ES5"`

Comment: I changed my "target": "es2019" to "target": "ES5" and it worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as the solution? Hunting reputation :)